# preg_match not redirecting properly

Tags: preg-match

I am using the following code to determine the proper redirect.  The top check matches as expected and selects the proper page to load, but the second check does not return a match and I end up being redirected to the default page.  I have compared the two lines until I can't see straight.  They look identical in form and function, other than the obvious difference in what I am trying to match of course.  What am I missing?  Is there another way to accomplish my goal that might be a better choice?  Thanks as always.

```
if (preg_match('/\Handicap Summer Foursomes/', $eventname)) {
    $form = '<a class="primary" href="signup_HSF.php?eid=' . $EID . '&squads=2">Sign-up</a>';
} else if (preg_match('/\Gigantic 5/', $eventname)) {
    $form = '<a class="primary" href="signup_G5.php?eid=' . $EID . '&squads=2">Sign-up</a>';
} else {
    $form = '<a class="primary" href="signup.php?eid=' . $EID . '&squads=2">Sign-up</a>';
}
```

Comment: what's with the `\H` and `\G`? Neither of those chars needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/\Handicap Summer Foursomes/', $eventname)) {
                 ^^
```

In preg, `\H` is "any character that is not a horizontal whitespace character". While this would match a literal `H`, because that's not a horiz-WS char, it's still an escape sequence you need to be aware of.

Ditto for `\G` in the other pattern. in preg, `\G` is "first matching position in subject". That's definitely not going to match.

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  I missed the proper usage of the \b in my code.  Works now!!

Comment: Tried to give you an upvote, but I am not a level 15 so it will not allow me to do so